# How to disable scrolling in Xamarin Android for NestedScrollView targeting KitKat?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-support-library

I'm working with Xamarin Studio, I'm using the Support Library to use the newer components in KitKat devices.

I have a NestedScrollView which I wish to disable it's scrolling for the purpose of handling a child view touch events.

My scenario is like this: I am animating the scrollview position on the Y axis by detecting the touch event action MOVE on the top child view added to the scrollview, when a movement to the bottom is detected the scrollview is animated to a bottom position and then I make a scrollTo call to the top of the scrollview leave the first child on the scrollview visible, after that I want to disable the scrolling. When the child view detects a move motion to the top, I animate the scrollview Y position so the scrollview is fully visible, after this animation is done I want the scrolling to be enabled.

I have tried with:

```
currentScrollView.NestedScrollingEnabled = false;
```

But it throws a NoSuchMethodError, also I tried:

```
ViewCompat.SetNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

And with this the scrolling isn't disabled.

Is there a way to disable the scrolling in a NestedScrollView when targeting KitKat?

Comment: What's you mean "disable it's scrolling while it's position is at the bottom of it's parent view", could you please elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: I updated my question with a bit more details but in short I just want to disable the scrolling on a NestedScrollView when targeting to KitKat.